# characters change in a string loop in C

Tags: c

I am getting a string as an input.
and im trying to get the most repeated letter in the string.
but somehow the string changes in the loop and I don't know why.
here's the code:

```
char str[1000];
int counts[26] = {0};
fgets (str, 1000, stdin);    
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++) {
    counts[abs(tolower(str[i])-97)]++;
}
printf("%s",str);
```

input is :

```
For a guy who was chosen by his father as the only son to be taught the secrets of this martial art, he doesn't have much of a kick.
```

the output is :

```
For a guy who was chosen by his father as the only son to be taught the secrets of this martjal art,!he doesn't have muci of a kick.
```

as you can see the word `martial` turns to `martjal` and `much` turns to `muci`
I can't understand what am I doing in the loop that changes the string.
can anyone explain, please? I am a newbie in c.

Comment: whitespace overflows `counts[26]`

Comment: What happens when counting the spaces?

Comment: First, fix the bug in your program. For the first letter 'F', 'F' - 97 = -27. tolower(-27)  = -27 as from man pages: `The value returned is that of the converted letter, or c if the conversion was not possible.`. Now, abs(-27) = 27. So, now you are doing counts[27]++ which is wrong as per your requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, accessing an array beyond its size is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and your program is doing it here:

```
    counts[abs(tolower(str[i])-97)]++;
```

When `str[i]` is space character (`' '`) then `tolower(str[i])` returns unmodified `str[i]` whose ascii value is `32`. Next is `abs(32 - 97)` which returns `65`. This value `65` is used as index of `counts` array - `counts[65]`. Note that `counts` is an array of `26` elements of type `int`. It's index range is `0 - 25`. Accessing `counts[65]` is undefined behaviour<sup>1)</sup>.

> *im trying to get the most repeated letter in the string.*

If you just want to find out the most repeated letter, simply keep the counts of letters only and skip other characters from input string.

You can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NUM_CHARS 26
#define INPUT_SZ  1000

int main (void) {
    char str[INPUT_SZ];
    int counts[NUM_CHARS] = {0};

    printf ("Enter string:\n");
    if (fgets (str, INPUT_SZ + 1, stdin) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to read input\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        int ch = tolower(str[i]);
        if ((ch >= 'a') && (ch <= 'z')) {
            counts[ch - 97]++;
        }
    }

    int max = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < NUM_CHARS; ++i) {
        if (counts[max] < counts[i]) {
            max = i;
        }
    }

    fprintf (stdout, "Input string :\n%s\n", str);
    fprintf (stdout, "Character with maximum occurrence : %c, occurrence count : %d\n", 'a' + max, counts[max]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
# ./a.out
Enter string:
For a guy who was chosen by his father as the only son to be taught the secrets of this martial art, he doesn't have much of a kick.
Input string :
For a guy who was chosen by his father as the only son to be taught the secrets of this martial art, he doesn't have much of a kick.

Character with maximum occurrence : h, occurrence count : 11
```

---

Below part is for OP and enthusiasts only:

Whenever a program includes undefined behaviour, all bets are off. We should not even try find out the reason behind the program output because  tomorrow we may get different output as compare to the output we are getting today, on same platform.

Unfortunately, the output that you are getting, I am also getting the exact same output - word `martial` turns to `martjal` and `much` turns to `muci` etc. and, out of curiosity, I thought to dig it a little and it turned out to be the way the `str` and `counts` are placed in the memory. Below is the cause of outcome that we are getting:

The address of `counts` is `0x00007ffeefbff540`
and the address of `str` is `0x00007ffeefbff5b0`

The difference between two addresses:

```
0x00007ffeefbff5b0 - 0x00007ffeefbff540 = 0x70 (in decimal 112)
```

The `counts` is placed before `str`. Its an array of `int`'s and size of `int` on my platform is `4`. Total bytes occupied by `counts` is - `26 * 4 = 104 bytes`.

Hypothetically, the layout would be:

```
+---------  104 bytes ----------+-8 bytes--+------ 1000 bytes ----------------------+ 
                                |          |
| | | | | |........ 26 ints.....| | |..| | | | | | | |.......... 1000 chars...| | | |
^                               ^          ^                                        ^
|                               |          |                                        |
|                (0x00007ffeefbff540       |                                        |
counts            + sizeof (counts))       |                       (0x00007ffeefbff5b0
(0x00007ffeefbff540)                       |                            + sizeof (str))
                                           |
                                          str
                                         (0x00007ffeefbff5b0)
```

The only characters, in the given input, of our interest are - `,` (comma), `'` (appstrophe), `.` (dot) and `' '`(space) because these characters are leading to undefined behaviour.

Lets start with `,` (comma) first.

```
Breaking down this statement - counts[abs(tolower(str[i])-97)]++
str[i] = ','
tolower(',') will return 44 (ASCII value of ',' character)
abs (44 - 97)  =>  abs (-53)  =>  53
counts[53]++

53 * 4 = 212 (as the size of int on my platform is 4)
base address of "counts" array is 0x00007ffeefbff540
0x00007ffeefbff540 + 0xD4 (hex of 212) = 0x00007ffeefbff614

offset of 0x00007ffeefbff614 from "str" array base address
0x00007ffeefbff614 - 0x00007ffeefbff5b0 = 0x64 (hex of 100)

str[100] is space character ' ' which comes just after the ',' (comma) character  
So, counts[53] will give value at address 0x00007ffeefbff614.
counts[53] value is 543516704 (note that its 4 byte value at address 0x00007ffeefbff614)

Binary of 543516704:

3rd byte | 2nd byte | 1st byte | 0th byte (address 0x00007ffeefbff614)
00100000 | 01100101 | 01101000 | 00100000
  ' '        'e'        'h'        ' '

i.e. 4 bytes just after the ',' character.
Note that you are post incrementing the value at given index in counts array.
So, counts[53]++ will result in adding 1 to byte at that address which 
is space character

' ' + 1  =>  32 + 1  =>  33  =>  '!' 

So, after counts[53]++ the input string 100th character is changed to '!':
"................art,!he doesn't.............."
                     ^
                     |
```

`'` (appstrophe) character:

```
str[i] = '''
tolower(''') will return 39 (ASCII value of ''' character)
abs (39 - 97)  =>  abs (-58)  =>  58
counts[58]++

58 * 4 = 232 (as the size of int on my platform is 4)
base address of "counts" array is 0x00007ffeefbff540
0x00007ffeefbff540 + 0xE8 (hex of 232) = 0x00007ffeefbff628

offset of 0x00007ffeefbff628 from "str" array base address
0x00007ffeefbff628 - 0x00007ffeefbff5b0 = 0x78 (hex of 120)

str[120] is character 'h', the last character of word "much" in the str string
So, counts[58] will give value at address 0x00007ffeefbff628.
counts[53] value is 1718558824 (note that its 4 byte value at address 0x00007ffeefbff628)

Binary of 1718558824:

3rd byte | 2nd byte | 1st byte | 0th byte (address 0x00007ffeefbff628)
01100110 | 01101111 | 00100000 | 01101000
  'f'        'o'        ' '        'h'

counts[58]++ will result in adding 1 to byte at that address which 
is character 'h'

'h' + 1  =>  104 + 1  =>  105  =>  'i' 

So, after counts[53]++ the input string 120th character is changed to '!':
".......................have muci of a ......"
                                ^
                                |
```

`.` (dot) character:

```
str[i] = '.'
tolower('.') will return 46 (ASCII value of '.' character)
abs (46 - 97)  =>  abs (-51)  =>  51
counts[51]++

51 * 4 = 204 (as the size of int on my platform is 4)
base address of "counts" array is 0x00007ffeefbff540
0x00007ffeefbff540 + 0xCC (hex of 204) = 0x00007ffeefbff60c

offset of 0x00007ffeefbff60c from "str" array base address
0x00007ffeefbff60c - 0x00007ffeefbff5b0 = 0x5C (hex of 92)

str[92] is character 'i', which exists in word "martial" in the str string
So, counts[51] will give value at address 0x00007ffeefbff60c.
counts[51] value is 543973737 (note that its 4 byte value at address 0x00007ffeefbff60c)

Binary of 543973737:

3rd byte | 2nd byte | 1st byte | 0th byte (address 0x00007ffeefbff60c)
00100000 | 01101100 | 01100001 | 01101001
  ' '        'l'        'a'        'i'

counts[51]++ will result in adding 1 to byte at that address which 
is character 'i'

'i' + 1  =>  105 + 1  =>  106  =>  'j' 

So, after counts[51]++ the input string 92th character is changed to 'j':
".......................this martjal art, ........"
                                 ^
                                 |
```

Similarly, if you are really willing to and still you are getting same outcome on your system, you can decode for `' '` (space) character as well :).

---

1). An undefined behaviour includes it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.

Comment: ASCII Art worthy of the nod alone....